# Configure TYPO3 Crawler Extension

Tags: typo3

I followed [this](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/tutoriels/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html) tutorial to index some files in the fileadmin. Now I am at the point "Then manually process the entry: (...)". The problem is that I get this errormessage when I click on the green "refresh-Button":

[image]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and why I am not authorized to Crawl through my page as the message: `Error: 401 Authorization Required Authorization R...` tells me.

By the way: i did not forget to add the user: _cli_crawler .

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using HTTP Authentication in your project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have use `HTTP Authentication` in your project then you can use baseUrl something like below. For more details [clike here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/crawler/ExtCrawler/Configuration/HttpAuthentication/Index.html)

```
http://user:pass@www.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: ah how could i forget this.. yes thats right. I tried it with the base url and the ID and Password but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Ok now it worked. I guess TYPO3 needed some time to update the baseurl. Thanks

Comment: Welcome @MatthiasGwiozda

Answer (score 1):

I think you add **htpassword** in your site that prevent pages to being indexed.

[image]

so remove first htaccess password protection and after try to reindex again.